# Broadcast receiver sends notification continues

Tags: android

I am new in android development. I am developing an app in which I send notification when new rows inserted in database using broadcast receiver. I am calling this function in every 10 seconds. If I insert 2 rows in database then my app sends notification "2 new message received". Its working fine. The problem is notification is already showing in notification but my app sending notification continuously in every 10 seconds. I want to if notification is showing in notification bar for the same rows then do not resend notification. Please help me. Here is my code..

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class SampleBC extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static int noOfTimes = 0;
    private RegistrationOperation RegistrationOperation;

    // Method gets called when Broad Case is issued from MainActivity for every 10 seconds
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        noOfTimes++;
        //Toast.makeText(context, "BC Service Running for " + noOfTimes + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();


        RegistrationOperation = new RegistrationOperation(context);
        RegistrationOperation.open();

        String lastsyncdate = RegistrationOperation.LastSyncDate();
        params.put("date", lastsyncdate);

        final GlobalVariable glbvrbl = new GlobalVariable();

        // Checks if new records are inserted in Remote MySQL DB to proceed with Sync operation
        client.post(glbvrbl.path+"and_getrowcount.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                try 
                {

                    // Create JSON object out of the response sent by getdbrowcount.php
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    System.out.println(obj.get("count"));
                    // If the count value is not zero, call MyService to display notification
                    if(obj.getInt("count") != 0){

                        if(!(context.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                                        .getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName())))
                        {
                            //app is in foreground;
                            final Intent intnt = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                            // Set unsynced count in intent data
                            intnt.putExtra("intntdata", obj.getInt("count") + " New News Recieved");
                            // Call MyService
                            context.startService(intnt);
                        }


                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Sync not needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                String content) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(statusCode == 404){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "404", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(statusCode == 500){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "500", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: hey...i have come across with this situation. But i have used GCM for sending notifications.In your code of sending notification, you just update the pending intent.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest not to use Broadcast Receiver in your scenario as it might drain the battery. (Since yo are checking for every 10 sec) I would suggest you to go with Android GCM where Google Cloud Server will send the Notifications on your behalf. Please refer the links.  [Link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) [Link 2](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/). Hope this might help you.

Cheers.